# SQL error in select expected as, id , quoted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Oracle SQL select and I need to use it also in SQL Server. I'm trying to make it work on SQL Server but I receive an error:

> Unexpected syntax near WHERE. Expecting as,id quoted_id.

This is the select I'm trying to make work in SQL Server

```sql
SELECT 
    id,
    nombre,
    activado
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         id,
         nombre,
         activado
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              id_var id,
              nombre_var nombre,
              1 activado
          FROM 
              nombres
          ORDER BY 
              nombre DESC)
     WHERE 
         ROWNUM = 1)
```

Comment: Your subqueries have no aliases. An object in the `FROM` **must** have a name or alias.

Comment: Also you have an `ORDER BY` in your subquery, that isn't allowed (unless there is a `TOP`), *and* you outer-inner subquery references a column `ROWNUM`, but your inner subquery has no such column defined.

Comment: @Larnu  So I should put alias for every subquerie right¿ this doesn´t happens on oracle only sql server :(

Comment: T-SQL and PL/SQL are different dialects of SQL @wty . You should not expect valid PL/SQL to be valid T-SQL syntax, and vice versa.

Comment: thanks going to check that

Comment: It looks like you just need the topmost row from the resultant data after sorting in descending?  If that is the case, then this query can be simplified a lot. 
Just use select top 1 in sql query

Comment: Think you're missing a closing bracket also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Oracle but I assume you want to return the first row. This is done is SQL Server the following way

```
SELECT TOP 1 id_var id, nombre_var nombre, 1 activado
FROM nombres
ORDER BY nombre DESC
```

Comment: yes , this works but also I have to put an alias for subquery

Comment: @wty what do you mean with alias? My solution contains aliases for id_var (which is id), nombre_var (which is nombre), and 1 (activado)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a version that works in (recent versions) of either database:

```
SELECT id_var as id, nombre_var as nombre, 1 as activado
FROM nombres
ORDER BY nombre DESC
OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

This is, in fact, Standard SQL.